# Extension css button confliction with other websites

Tags: css

I am creating new extension now my css is conlfiction with some of websites

i have follwing css

```
ul.myextentiontagit input[type="text"] {
  width:100px;

}
```

and website have like

```
    input[type="text"] {
          height:1200px;
          line-height: 120px;
    }
```

now my exeantion is also picking website css.

What is the best way to write css for that.

**Edit:** i already added pre-class name **myextention** in all css.still it is conflicting. even after clearing cache and everyhting

Answer (score 1):

To avoid conflicts you can use Namespaces.That will avoid many conflicts.Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This common when you are putting your HTML and CSS code inside the other webpages.

To differentiate between your and other website CSS, you need to use specific CSS selectors for elements styling.

Some like following you have to use -

```
<!-- Website CSS-->
--- whatever here it is ---


<!-- your CSS --->
.my-container .my-button{

}

<!-- your HTML-->

<div class="my-container">
   <div class="my-button"> My Button </div>  
</div>
```

Now, whatever CSS other website has it will not conflict with yours , beacuase you have given specific selector for styling